# Can I connect 2 different PSU's to 1 GPU?

Tags: litecoin, mining-hardware, gpu

I have 2 PSU's 850W and 750W 1 motherboard and 4 cards 280x GPU's.
I would like to connect 2 of the GPU's to a second PSU.
So it means 2 cards are powered by PSU A. and 2 by PSU A via the motherboard and PSU B via the 8 and 6 pin connectors.

Will that be OK? Because I heard that you shouldn't connect a GPU to 2 seperate PSU's.

Do I have to buy powered raisers for the 2 GPU's?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware setup.

Comment: Di you find ever find the answer you were looking for? If not, I will do some digging through my bookmarks to help you out.